# How do I access a value from a method of my simple type?

Tags: glib, vala

If I want to create my simple type, how can I access its value from the type method?
For example:

```
[IntegerType (rank = 6, signed = true, width = 32)]
[SimpleType]
[CCode (has_type_id = false)]
struct foo_t {
    public string say_hello(){
        return(@"Hello from new foo_t type");
    }
    public int x10(){
        return this.value * 10;
    }
}
```

Here `this.value` throws an error `The name 'value' does not exist`.
`say_hello` works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was extremely simple, there is no hidden `value` field, just `this` is the current value.

```
[IntegerType (rank = 6, signed = true, width = 32)]
[SimpleType]
[CCode (has_type_id = false)]
struct foo_t {
    public int x10(){
        return this * 10;
    }
}
void main () {
    foo_t foo = 5;
    prin(foo.x10());
}


[Print]
inline void prin (string str) {
    stdout.printf (str + "\n");
}
```

Works fine!